# System design for consuming third party APIs

Tags: api, design-patterns

I have a CRM system. I need to implement grabbing Contacts’/Accounts’ data from third party APIs by user provided IDs and loading details into CRM. The problem is that API responses may differ e.g. by Accounts’ legal form or something like that. Moreover I need to check received responses against other corporate internal information systems. I understand OOP and all that stuff rather well. But everything still looks very tangled and tedious. And I wonder if there are any methodology(ies) of working with external data. Any books to read or videos to watch? Any well-known design patterns for such tasks? Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look into adding an anti-corruption layer to your application. In short it is a layer of code that consumes your 3rd party APIs and maps the results into objects defined by your own app, stripping out useless information and allowing you to dictate what the integration should look like. You will have some messy mappers inside this layer. But any data escaping this layer should be easy to use for the rest of your app.
[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used) will explain in more detail.